# Admin login with Google reCaptcha

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, security, admin-login

I would like to know if there is an extension or if someone has successfully added a Google reCaptcha to the admin login so it makes it harder to try automated password attacks

Comment: Why don't you use Magento native Captcha for the admin panel? You can enable this is `System > Configuration > Advanced > Admin > CAPTCHA > Enable CAPTCHA in Admin`.

Answer (score 2):

There's also this one: https://github.com/ProxiBlue/recaptcha but I think the implementation is fairly similar.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found an extension https://github.com/noglitchyo/mage-google-recaptcha/